# Ошибка - TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python

Начал изучение Python, не смог найти здесь ошибку TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

```
from pyowm import OWM
from pyowm.utils import config
from pyowm.utils import timestamps
from pyowm.utils.config import get_default_config
config_dict = get_default_config()
config_dict['language']="ru"
import telebot

owm = OWM('токен')
mgr = owm.weather_manager()
bot = telebot.TeleBot("токен")

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def send_echo(message):
   observation = mgr.weather_at_place(message.text)
   w = observation.weather
   temp = w.temperature('celsius')['temp']
   answer = "В городе " + message.text + " сейчас " + w.detailed_status() + "\n\n"
   answer += "Температура сейчас в районе " + str(temp) + "\n\n"
   if temp >= -20:
      answer += "На улице очень холодно, одевай шубу!!"
   elif temp < -10:
      answer += "На улице прохладно, одевайся теплее!"
   else:
      answer += "На улице не очень холодно, одевайся как хочешь"
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, answer)
bot.polling( none_stop = True)
```

Comment: на какой именно строке?

Comment: Если правильно понял получается после temp строка

Comment: answer = "В городе " + message.text + " сейчас " + w.detailed_status() + "\n\n"

Comment: эт значит что `w.detailed_status` не функция, а строка и поэтому её вызывает не надо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по [документации (get started)](https://github.com/csparpa/pyowm#get-started) `w.detailed_status` не функция, а параметр, поэтому к ней обращаться не надо:

```py
answer = "В городе " + message.text + " сейчас " + w.detailed_status + "\n\n"
```

Исправленный код с русским языком

```py
from pyowm import OWM
from pyowm.utils import config
from pyowm.utils import timestamps
from pyowm.utils.config import get_default_config
config_dict = get_default_config()
config_dict['language']="ru"
import telebot

owm = OWM('токен', config_dict)
mgr = owm.weather_manager()
bot = telebot.TeleBot("токен")

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def send_echo(message):
    observation = mgr.weather_at_place(message.text)
    w = observation.weather
    temp = w.temperature('celsius')['temp']
    answer = "В городе " + message.text + " сейчас " + w.detailed_status + "\n\n"
    answer += "Температура сейчас в районе " + str(temp) + "\n\n"
    if temp >= -20:
        answer += "На улице очень холодно, одевай шубу!!"
    elif temp < -10:
        answer += "На улице прохладно, одевайся теплее!"
    else:
        answer += "На улице не очень холодно, одевайся как хочешь"
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, answer)
bot.polling( none_stop = True)
```