# Ошибка: TypeError: 'str' object is not callable, как исправить?

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, бот

```
import pyowm
import telebot
from pyowm.owm import OWM
from pyowm.utils.config import get_default_config


owm = OWM('522...6ab')
mgr = owm.weather_manager()

config_dict = get_default_config()
config_dict['ru'] = 'pt'  # your language here, eg. Portuguese

bot = telebot.TeleBot("153...891:AAH...g3U")


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def send_echo(message):
    observation = mgr.weather_at_place(message.text)
    w = observation.weather
    temp = w.temperature('celsius')['temp']
    status = w.detailed_status()

    answer = "В городе " + message.text + " сейчас " + str(temp) + " градусов! " + "Сейчас " + str(status)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, answer)

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Ошибка на 21 строке `status = w.detailed_status()`

Comment: если честно не сильно вникал в код но первое что приходит на ум `status = w.detailed_status` прописать так. без (). Ошибка все еще есть?

Comment: @Kers совершенно прав. Кстати, спасибо за токен бота.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ошибка - TypeError: 'str' object is not callable](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1230515/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-typeerror-str-object-is-not-callable)

Answer (score 2):

Все таки занялся проверкой кода:
смените строку:
`status = w.detailed_status()`
на
`status = w.detailed_status`

После этого бот работает )
Ошибка указывает что строку нельзя вызвать как функцию.